# using os.system in python to run program with parameters

Tags: python

How do I get python to run sudo openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn --config client.ovpn

I'm trying the following at the minute without success

```
vpnfile2 = '/etc/init.d/openvpn'
cfgFile = 'client.ovpn'

os.system('sudo \"" + vpnFile2 + "\" --cd \"" + vpnpath + "\" --config \"" + cfgFile + "\"')
```

Comment: I'm not certain that executing sudo in this context will work. I believe you need an interactive session in order to run commands with sudo. Consider omitting the "sudo" and instead running the Python script with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: @chradcliffe, easy enough to try it `subprocess.call(['sudo', 'cat', '/etc/shadow'])` :) Works ok on Karmic by the way! Perhaps some versions of sudo don't

Comment: @gnibbler You're right. I guess it just seems a little odd to do it this way; however, I suppose if you only need privilege escalation for a single command, you could make a case for this approach.

Answer (score 8):

use the `subprocess` module

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['sudo', vpnFile2, '--cd', vpnpath, '--config', cfgFile])
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been posted awhile ago, but if someone comes across this (like me), there is another way to get privileges using the os.system method ..

It will only work if you are running this in a GUI environment.
You can simply try to call it with 'gksu' or ('kdesu' or 'kdesudo'), it would look like this in a gnome session:

```
import os
vpnfile2 = '/etc/init.d/openvpn'
cfgFile = 'client.ovpn'

os.system('gksu \"" + vpnFile2 + "\" --cd \"" + vpnpath + "\" --config \"" + cfgFile + "\"')
```

The prompt works, but I have not tested it to work with your code.

Answer (score 0):

If there is some reason you want to use os.system, instead of subprocess, I usually wash it through bash, so 
    `os.system('''sudo bash -c "command to run"''')` (Or sh or whatever shell you have).  It processes the arguments better in many cases.