# How to call value from python to shell?

Tags: python, shell

```
import os  
url='http://106.3.62.196/mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2011/3/U/1/S6V22L0U1.mp4?wsiphost=local'
os.system("wget -c $url  -O  test")
```

The os.system statement can not run .
How to send the value of url in python to shell command here?

Comment: Please read this thread.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398095/using-os-system-in-python-to-run-program-with-parameters

Comment: You are using perl/sh-style variable interpolation ("$url"), which doesn't work in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
os.system("wget -c $url  -O  test")
```

With

```
os.system("wget -c %s -O  test" % url )
```

You might also want to see if something like subprocess.call() would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
import os  
url='http://106.3.62.196/mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2011/3/U/1/S6V22L0U1.mp4?wsiphost=local'
os.system("wget -c "+url+" -O  test")
```

However, in most cases, this is not the best and certainly not the most portable way to download a file from python.